# Background image to always be in the same spot when content size changes

Tags: html, css

I have a button which has an arrow icon as an image. I want the arrow to always be `20px` from the text and border of the div.

However, when the text length changes the text covers the arrow image.

I know the issue lies in `width: 205px`, but even when setting the width to `auto`, the image is still covered.

```css
.download a{
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 205px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #dc0b22;
    padding: 24px 1.2em;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 1em;
    background-color: #dc0b22;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-image: url(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/160143/Tomorrow%20People/Template%20Builds/white-arrow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top 50% right 28px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="download">
    <a href="">example text here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: So increase the padding on the right side, so that it will preserve more space for your triangle thingie there …?

Comment: I'm sure It can be achieved but It must also look good when it is displayed on the page. Why don't you want the arrow on to the center-right of the button, that will look good for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `background-size:wwpx hhpx;`

Where `ww` and `hh` are width and height.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you move the arrow to a different `span` and then use `absolute` positioning?

checkout this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yLmgd17/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set min-width to some minimal value, so that should fix things. Just add min-width:205px!important;
Here is the code:

```css
.download a{
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 205px!important;
    width: 205px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #dc0b22;
    padding: 24px 1.2em;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 1em;
    background-color: #dc0b22;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-image: url(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/160143/Tomorrow%20People/Template%20Builds/white-arrow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top 50% right 28px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="download">
        <a href="">example text here</a>
    </div>
```